# Difficulty in sql select query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have three tables office, manager,staff. Below are the contents of these tables.

**Office**

```
     office_id  office_location  office_telephone  office_fax

     100        brisbane         01438263          789
     101        newyork          01457899          978
     102        chicago          01457989          789
```

**Manager**

```
     office_id  manager_id  manager_name  manager_phone

     100        200         wayne         9879664878
     101        201         tom           9745997669     
     102        202         harry         9789979799
```

**Staff**

```
     manager_id  staff_id  salary

     200         300       3000
     201         301       4000
     200         302       5000
     200         303       7856
     201         304       4000
     202         305       7856
     202         306       6000
```

Now, I need a query to display the total number of staff and their manager at each office.

Here is the sample output

```
    office_id  office_location  manager_id  count(staff_id)

    100        brisbane         200         3
    101        newyork          201         2
    102        chicago          202         2
```

Till now I have tried is displaying the manager_id and staff working for them.

```
     SELECT manager_id,count(staff_id) from staff group by manager_id;
```

But I am having trouble to display the office_id as well as it's location. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please provide sample output for the data that you've given.

Comment: aah just forgot it. Will provide it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT o.office_id, 
       o.office_location, 
       m.manager_id, 
       count(*) staff_count
  from staff s
 inner join manager m
    on m.manager_id = s.manager_id
 inner join office o
    on o.office_id = m.office_id
 group by o.office_id, 
          o.office_location,
          m.manager_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner query gets count and total salary per single manager first... THEN, work down the chain to get rest of details

```
SELECT
      s.manager_id,
      m.manager_name,
      m.manager_phone,
      o.office_location,
      o.office_telephone,
      o.office_fax,
      s.NumOfEmployees,
      s.AllSalary
   from
      ( select s1.manager_id,
               count(*) as NumEmployees,
               SUM( s1.salary ) as AllSalary
            from staff s1
            group by s1.manager_id ) s
         join manager m
            ON m.manager_id = m.manager_id
            join office o
               ON m.office_id = o.office_id
```

Comment: But it won't display the staff number. Can you please look at the sample output and provide me some help.

Answer (score 0):

I just created the tables and data you mentioned above and if you just want the columns you mentioned in the output you can just use following:

```
SELECT O.office_id
    ,office_location
    ,M.manager_id
    ,COUNT(staff_id)
FROM Staff S
INNER JOIN Manager M
    ON S.manager_id = M.manager_id
INNER JOIN Office O
    ON O.office_id = M.office_id
GROUP BY M.manager_id
    ,O.office_id
    ,O.office_location
```